# Error al llamar un stored procedure en c#

Tags: c#, windows-forms

tengo un problema al querer llamar un stored procedure en c#, el stored procedure es buscar un nombre de un cliente, ya lo intente con el select lo cual me funciona pero al querer usar un stored procedure no me funciona alguien me podria ayudar

me funciona de esta manera, estoy usando un textbox lo cual al poner el nombre del cliente me lo muestra en el datagridView pero al querer hacerlo con el stored procedure no me funciona

```
public DataTable Buscar(string descripcion)
        {
            connectionSql.Open();
         SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(string.Format("SELECT * FROM CATALOGO WHERE NAMECLIENTE LIKE '%{0}%'",descripcion), connectionSql);
           SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            ds = new DataSet();
            ad.Fill(ds,"@NAME");
            connectionSql.Close();
            return ds.Tables["@NAME"];
        }
```

lo hice de esta manera pero me marca un error

```
public DataTable Buscar(string descripcion)
    {

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("CALL SP_BUSCAR", connectionSql);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        connectionSql.Open();

       SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        ds = new DataSet();
            ad.Fill(ds,"TABLA");//AQUI LO CAMBIE POR @NAME PERO NO FUNCIONA
//QUE ES EL WHERE DEL STORED PROCEDURE
                connectionSql.Close();
                return ds.Tables["TABLA"];
            }
```

[image: eroor]

```
DataTable dtresultado = new  DataTable();
        try
        {

            SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("CALL SP_BUSCAR",connectionSql);
            sqlcmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            connectionSql.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter sqlDat = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcmd);
            sqlDat.Fill(dtresultado);
            sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connectionSql.Close();

        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            dtresultado = null;
        }
        return dtresultado;
```

Comment: Omite la instrucción CALL. Por otro lado, si el método retorna un tipo DataTable, crea una instancia de tipo DataTable, es innecesario crear una instancia de tipo DataSet.

Comment: te refieres a esto DataTable dtresultado = new  DataTable();
            try
            {

                SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("CALL SP_BUSCAR",connectionSql);
                sqlcmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                connectionSql.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter sqlDat = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcmd);
                sqlDat.Fill(dtresultado);
                sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                connectionSql.Close(); igual no me funciona

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Omite la instrucción CALL. Por otro lado, si el método retorna un tipo DataTable, crea una instancia de tipo DataTable, es innecesario crear una instancia de tipo DataSet.

```
public DataTable Buscar(string descripcion)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Cadena de conexión"))
        {
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SP_BUSCAR", conn);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            //da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Descripcion", descripcion);

            da.Fill(dt);

            return dt;
        }
    }
```